# error WriteBlob Failed using ImageMagick 6.7.9

Tags: php, imagemagick

I want to create an image from a pdf file. I have installed ImageMagick on a Linux server
and successfully created an image from a terminal with root access.

**Command:**

```
 /usr/local/bin/convert http://www.artisticancestry.com/sites/default/files/media/Getting%20Started_7.pdf /public_html/testing.png
```

But When i am going to execute this command from php exec() function. It is showing this type of error

**error:**
     convert: unable to open image `/public_html/testing-0.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642.
     convert: WriteBlob Failed`/public_html/testing-0.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1751.

There is some permission issue but don't know which file has no permission.How can I find out what is causing this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: My problem was that the folder doesn't exist...

Comment: My problem was I had "file:/" at the beginning of the path...

Answer (score 22):

It was a permission issue for me

chmod -R 777 /dir

/dir = Directory where you want to writing your image

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. The issue was a wrong folder name. You need to use the full path to the file from the system root, or relative path without / as first symbol.

Comment: I didn't get this " - and its be - wrong folder name"

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue for me too.

I give the full permission to the `cache` folder which was present inside `tcpdf` folder.

`chmod 0777 -R cache/`

Comment: I think you can just give these permissions to the folder only.