# Uncaught ImagickException: WriteBlob Failed

Tags: php, imagemagick, silverstripe, imagick

Currently getting the following error:

> Error at framework/filesystem/ImagickBackend.php line 25: Uncaught ImagickException: unable to open image `/{project-root}/assets/Ad_202.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695 ({localhost}/admin/flyers/FlyerAd/EditForm/field/FlyerAd/item/202/ItemEditForm)

At first I thought that maybe it was a permissions issue on my assets folder, as per this thread: [error WriteBlob Failed using ImageMagick 6.7.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298893/error-writeblob-failed-using-imagemagick-6-7-9). But even after running `chmod -R 777 assets`, the issue persists.

Any suggestions?

I'm running php 5.3, and have imagick extension installed and enabled.

Comment: Seems like the file doesn't exist at this path?

Comment: you should check that the directory actually exists with var_dump(realpath("/{project-root}/assets"));