# Convert SVG to PNG image

Tags: php

I have tried to convert the svg to png image . I have used below php code.

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob(file_get_contents('image.svg'));
$image->setImageFormat("png24");
$image->resizeImage(1024, 768, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1); 
$image->writeImage('image.png');
```

The below error was found

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'WriteBlob Failed `image.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1645' in /var/www/html/image.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/image.php(8): Imagick->writeimage('image.png') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/image.php on line 8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you figure it out ? i mean did you solved it ? still needs help ?

Comment: No, Still error occured

Comment: are you uploading imgs ? or they are already exist ?

Comment: Already exists, I need one more help, How can set the background for all g tags

Comment: lol one by one .  lets fix the first issue .

Comment: Okay Thanks, I will focus first issue.

Comment: Hi Lathin, Still this error occured al error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `

Comment: just posted an answer , check it and let me know the results , please read the info pretty good .

Comment: Okay i will try and let you Know

Comment: Hi Tried the below error  found,   Warning: file_get_contents(original/test.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/svgtopng/test.php on line 19

Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image in /var/www/html/svgtopng/test.php on line 19

Warning: imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/svgtopng/test.php on line 19   I have give all permission, to files, SVG file size is 2.8 Kb, What was wrong

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please see the above comments

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(original/test.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/svgtopng/test.php on line 19

Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image in /var/www/html/svgtopng/test.php on line 19

Warning: imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/svgtopng/test.php on line 19

Comment: The img you are up uploading should be svg

Comment: Just edited my answer again forgot to change final_name to filename

Comment: can you give your gmail id

Comment: i had some changes your cod, But still some error occuring,

Comment: Please gmail chant

Comment: i will send invitation name "Shanmuga Kumar"

Answer (score 0):

So i asked you if the imgs already exist or you are uploading them , you said they are already exist , but we are going to work on the idea that you are uploading the, then converting them .

First just like always a form to upload an image :

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="img">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Second , create 2 folders , one for the main images and the second for the converted images .

- First folder name is " original "
- Second folder name is " converted "

Now create a page called test.php in the same folder as the html page .

Here we are going to take the original images and upload it to the first folder and then call it back and convert it and store the new image in the second folder .

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name']; // getting the name of the uploaded img 
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $folder1="original/"; 
        $folder2="converted/";

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder1.$filename)) // moving the uploaded or the original img to the folder 1 
            {
                rename($folder1.$filename,$folder1.$filename.".SVG"); // adding SVG ext to the file name 
                $newext =  substr($filename,0, -3);  // taking the .SVG string from the file name 
                imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($folder1.$filename)),$folder2.$newext."png"); // Bring the file from folder 1 and add .png to its file name and then moving it to folder 2

            }
        else
        {
            echo "Something wrong with moving the file ";
        }
    else
    {
        echo "submit did not done ";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible solutions:

- Check whether the path is right and that there are file writing permissions for the 'image.png'

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298893/error-writeblob-failed-using-imagemagick-6-7-9).

- Use writeImageFile instead of writeImage ##

See [this post](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php#115359).